# Outlook: Function File functions not called in Desktop Client

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

How do i debug the function file of outlook addin. For some reason the add in works online but not on the desktop client.

In the past i found that some Javascript markups were not supported in desktop client.
So now i have changed my function file to a simplistic one, just to verify that functions are called when in desktop client. And i can say for a fact that the function `something` is not being called at all in the desktop client. The operation hangs forever. F12 debug tool shows not targets.

How do i debug this function file?

Function File

```
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    };
})();

function doIt(event) {
    console.log("Here");
    event.completed();
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
...
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
<OfficeTab id="appOrgTab">
    <Group id="appOrgCmdGroup">
        <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="appOrgCtrl">
            <Label resid="appOrgLabel"/>
            <Supertip>
                <Title resid="appOrgTitle"/>
                <Description resid="appOrgDesc"/>
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>doIt</FunctionName>
            </Action>
        </Control>
    </Group>
</OfficeTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
<Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="doIt"/>
</ExtensionPoint>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I turned out the issue was with my self signed certificate. With my addin as a task pane...i get to authorize the certificate in the pane. But since there is no such pane for function execution, the requests to my server are blocked.
I installed a valid certificate and it works now.